# Using subjunctive when referring to the past

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, subjonctif

If I wanted to say something to the effect of,
"It seems like it was just yesterday that we spoke about ..."
 I was thinking about using "il semble que..." which requires the subjunctive mood.

Therefore, would i simply say
"Il semble que ça soit juste hier que l'on se parlait de..." ?since this is in the context of spoken not literary french.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: In French "just" (only) is not rendered by "juste"  but by "seulement".

Answer (score 1):

*Il me semble que* should be followed by the indicative here because there is no uncertainty:

> *Il (me) semble que c'était hier que nous avons parlé de...*

You might also use *j'ai l'impression que...* or *on dirait que...* instead of *il (me) semble que...*.

Comment: Thanks. Is 'on se parlait' the incorrect tense to use? I had used the inperfect because it was an ongoing action in the past.

Comment: The imperfect would be used for a recurring event:  *Il semble que c'était chaque dimanche qu'on se parlait.*.